# Unhandled exception on user callback

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I do the following:

```
 float name[512][512][3]
```

I get this big error which causes me to break. I'm using Visual Studio.

I noticed simply putting "static" in front causes the error to go away, but I want this to be an instance field. I'm not sure why this is happening -- the array isn't that big and I have a powerful machine.

Trying [512][512] breaks me, but [256][512] is totally fine.

I'm at my wit's end! Help please :)

Comment: Do you understand how much memory is needed for `sizeof(float) * 512*512*3` ?, and what `static` means?

Comment: About 3 megabytes? And I believe static puts it on part of the heap, which can store more data? I don't know much!!

Comment: "the array isn't that big" - it's 3MB. While that's not much in terms of heap memory, it's a **lot** for stack. Are you creating a local variable of this type? Consider using `std::vector<float>` instead of arrays, or allocating the instance dynamically.

Comment: `static` will make it part of you module image. 3Mb may be too big, depending on how this variable is declared. A local in a function frame may well push the stack overboard.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations? Angew, could you give me some example code for how to allocate a 3D array dynamically?

Comment: Look at [/F (Set Stack Size)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx). This is the size you content against, likely. Default is 1MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is 3 MB (on most implementations of `float`). Objects of such size should only be allocated dynamically—3 MB is way too much for residing on the stack.

You have two options: one is to keep your class as-is, and make sure you only ever allocate it dynamically (using `new`, owned in a smart pointer).

The other, which I would prefer, is to use `std::vector<float>` instead of a 3-dimensional array, and implement the indexing around it as accessor functions. You could even wrap this vector & accessors in a class of their own, and use that as the type of your `name` data member.

The second option guarantees that the 3 MB of data will *never* reside in non-dynamic memory.

---

Here's one possible sketch of such a 3D-accessible `vector`:

```
template <class T, size_t Dim1, Dim2, Dim3>
class Array3d
{
  std::vector<T> data;

public:
  Array3d() : data(Dim1 * Dim2 * Dim3) {}

  T& at(size_t idx1, size_t idx2, size_t idx3)
  { return data[idx1 * Dim2 * Dim3 + idx2 * Dim3 + idx3); }

  T at(size_t idx1, size_t idx2, size_t idx3) const
  { return data[idx1 * Dim2 * Dim3 + idx2 * Dim3 + idx3); }
};
```

---

A more basic alternative would be to just dynamically allocate the array itself:

```
using Array2d = std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 512>;
std::unique_ptr<Array2d[]> name{new Array2d[512]};
name[i][j][k] = 42.0f;
```

Comment: Old Fortran hackers amongst us wouldn't call it `at` - we'd call it `operator ()`.  So the usage is `array3d(i,j,k) = 42.0f;`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I really appreciate the code for vector, but it's a bit above my level and I'd like to only stick to things I understand. Can you provide an example of dynamically allocating a 3D array? I tried "float* name = new float[512][512][3]", to no avail

Comment: @MartinBonner That's certainly a possibility. Or it could define `operator []` returning a proxy for chaining `[i][j][k]`. I just showed the principle, really.

Comment: @Jon Added a more basic alternative.

Comment: Thanks so much! It still seems a bit complex and I'm getting a few errors -- but I'll work through it and try to understand. Thanks again!